# PHP upload with dynamic url by action attribute.

Tags: javascript, php, matlab, upload, action

I am trying to upload matlab file using php onto my server. I need to pass this file as the part of php url so that I can take out this from url and pass on this to some code in custom shell script.

Here is the script I am using to change the URL but then the file is not uploading.

HTML Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
    var form = document.getElementById("phpForm");
    form.onsubmit = function(){
      var matlabfile = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
      var filename = matlabfile.value;
      var filename2=filename.replace(/^.*\\/, "");
      var filename3=filename2.substr(0, filename2.lastIndexOf('.'));
      window.location = "upload.php?matlabfile=" + filename3
      return false;
    };          
 };
</script>

                            <form action="" id="phpForm" method="post"
                            name="phpForm" enctype="multipart/form-data>
                                <table style=" text-align:center;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>File 1:</b> <input id=
                                        "fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload"
                                        type="file"></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input name="submit" type=
                                        "submit" value=
                                        "Upload Script"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $targetfolder = "";
    $targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) ;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']). " is uploaded";
    } 
    else {
           echo "Problem uploading file";
    }
    $var1=$_GET['matlabfile'];
    echo "<pre>$var1</pre>";
    echo "matlabfile : ".$_GET['matlabfile']."<br>";
    $output = shell_exec("./n.sh $var1 2>&1");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    ?>
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Looking forward to your replies.

Thanks and Best Regards,
Shivam Dixit

Comment: $_GET['matlabfile'] what is it? where did you put that input inside a form

Comment: You may not be able to do this. There are limits on URL parameter lengths and it seems likely they're less than the contents of your file.  Use POST.

Comment: @Indra : I am getting the error from the first part of the script ie Uploading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'return false;' is preventing the submission of the form, and then the file isn't uploaded. You're simply moving the user to another address.

Instead of

```
window.location = "upload.php?matlabfile=" + filename3;
return false;
```

try to set the form action to the url you want:

```
form.setAttribute('action', "upload.php?matlabfile=" + filename3);
```

Then, the user will be sent to the page you want, and the file will be uploaded :)

Comment: My url got changed with this, But still the file is not uploading.

Comment: Also When I use a sample php code for upload file it does work.

Comment: Also When I use a sample php code for upload file it does work.

'code' <?php

$target_path = "";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
Html:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>

Comment: Can't you use that then?

Comment: I used that only, but need to add more stuff to the page and then it stop uploading the files.

Comment: There is your problem then!